"Teacher numbers" or "Teacher number" in England have/has increased over time - and why?

Teacher numbers or teacher number in England have/has increased over time.

We normally say the number of teachers, so I always thought teacher number is the way to go. But according to my research, there are examples where people use "numbers" instead of "number" for the same place (see the sentences below), so I'm confused now.

Staff numbers were reduced because of budget cuts.
Shark numbers have dwindled as a result of hunting.


Use either "the number of teachers" (preferred)   or "teacher numbers" (less idiomatic in most contexts)

Why is it "numbers"? It's not like I'm talking about the numbers of teachers in two different places, e.g., England and the US.

idiom.  not logic

@KenAdams, you could be talking (subconciously) about the numbers of teachers in the different counties or school districts (by whatever named they're called) or even schools in England.

You can also talk simply about how "the number has increased" or "the numbers have increased" without the word "teacher(s)", where the former must refer to a single figure, while the latter is less precise and might mean the number in each school, or the numbers divided some other way, and suggests a more general change or tendency. With "over time" you're describing a general tendency rather than a precise statistic.
